# pagination in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I am trying to do a Pagination in React but I am getting an error that I don't really understand.
I am following these steps https://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/pEYPbY

```
class Reviews extends Component {
    state = { 
            currentPage: 1,
            reviewsPerPage: 2,
            reviews: []
         }

         componentDidMount() {
            this.getReviews();
        }

        getReviews() {
         fetch(`https://apiwe.herokuapp.com/reviews`)
             .then(response => response.json())
             .then(result => this.setState({ reviews: result }))
             .then(result => console.log(this.state.reviews))
             .catch(err => console.log(err));
     }


    handlePageChange = number => {
      this.setState({ currentPage: number });
    };

    render() { 
            const { currentPage, reviewsPerPage, reviews} = this.state

            console.log(this.state)
            const indexLastReview = currentPage * reviewsPerPage;
            const indexFirstReview = indexLastReview - reviewsPerPage;
            
           // HERE IS THE ERROR 

            const currentReviews = reviews.slice(indexFirstReview, indexLastReview);
            const renderReviews = currentReviews.map((review, index) => {
                return (
                    <li key={review.id}>
                        <figure>
                          <h3>
                              {review.review_name}
                          </h3>
                        </figure>
                      <p>
                          {review.review_text}
                      </p>
                    </li>
                )
            })
            
            const pageNumbers = [];
            for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(reviews.length / reviewsPerPage); i++) {
                pageNumbers.push(i);
            }

            const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map(number => {
                return (
                    <li
                        key={number}
                        id={number}
                        onClick={this.handlePageChange.bind(this)}
                    >
                        {number}
                    </li>
                );
            });

            return (
          <div>
            <ul>
              {renderReviews}
            </ul>
            <ul id="page-numbers">
              {renderPageNumbers}
            </ul>
          </div>
            )
    }
}
 
export default Reviews;
```

The first error I am getting is understandable:

```
TypeError: reviews.slice is not a function
```

And that's because my reviews is not an array, I need to get my data so I tried:

```
let allReviews = reviews.reviews
console.log(allReviews)
const currentReviews = allReviews.slice......
```

And now, `allReviews.slice` is giving me undefined, and also does my console.log(allReviews).

But I noticed, that before changing my `.slice`, so:

```
let allReviews = reviews.reviews
console.log(allReviews)
const currentReviews = reviews.slice......
```

I get the same error as the first one, as expected, but I get data in my `allReviews`. I am not sure how to tackle this so I would appreciate it if someone can give me a hand on how to approach this.

Comment: It will be nice if you put your code also in CodeSandbox and paste the link whenever possible. It's easier that way for others to play around and figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your fetch is async, render code is running before you get the results. This is normal. In the render method you just need to check whether the fetch returned results. You can render an empty div if `reviews.reviews` is null or undefined.

Comment: I thought having componentDidMount() would fix that problem?. Would you recommend wrap all the render in an if, and return and empty div if is null?

Comment: Yes, return empty div if null.

Comment: See this for an example https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Comment: Found the error and it was the stupidest thing. Basically, my pagination function was based on a json object and I was trying to call reviews.reviews inside, but was too late as it was trying to render over a JSON, so instead, inside my getReviews(), I setState with result.reviews and I didn't have a problem anymore. Thank you for your guidance, really helped for the understanding of the lifecycle